# Do you need to add 301 redirect rules into robots.txt for search engines when you specify them in .htaccess?

Tags: redirects, robots.txt

Do I need to add 301 redirects to the robots.txt file?

I will be adding the redirects to the .htaccess file, but not sure if the search engines need them in the robots.txt file as well to prevent any negative impact on rankings.

Comment: There s no redirect directive for the robots.txt file. That is not what it is there for. Redirects are handled by .Htaccess or similar mechanism depending upon the web server.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean and the nature of this redirect. Are you referring to redirecting the `robots.txt` file itself? Rather than implementing a redirect "**in** the robots.txt file" (which doesn't make sense, as closetnoc has already pointed out)?

Comment: The three possible meanings here are: 1. Redirect the robots.txt file itself, 2. Add some sort of redirect directive to robots.txt, or 3. Add disallow directives to robots.txt that correspond to each redirect.    While the question is somewhat unclear, I'm not voting to close because an answer could pretty easily address all of these.

Comment: My apologies for not providing what I am doing. I have developed a very outdated site in Wordpress and will be redirecting the .html pages to the new WP page URLs. From all the searching I did, I didn't read anything that specifically stated robots.txt file was not for that purpose. I really wanted to be sure before doing anything to ensure I didn't create any issues. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: "I didn't read anything that specifically stated robots.txt file was not for that purpose" - but did you read anything that suggested that might even be technically possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: no, no any redirection rules in the `robots.txt` file. Just because it is the wrong place for them. I would highly recommend to read standard specification of robots.txt [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) and [there](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt).

- `Robots.txt` is for bots, crawlers, spiders, coming automatically to read and save the content of your pages.
- Redirection rules are for server, to handle any/all requests, coming from human or software.

There is an approach, called `cloacking`, which was used by some not-so-white SEOs years ago. This approach is about special setup in the server configuration (like your `htaccess`) to recognize search engine bots by their user agents and redirect them to special location. According to this the human visitors are redirected to another special locations too.

The goal of this approach was: search engines get pages, which are SEO-optimized in such grade, that they are no longer comfortable to be used by human. Human visitors get served not-so-optimized pages, which however can be offhand used.

By now Google is very good able to recognize and penalize such behavior - cloacking violates Google's ToS.